# Why does Intellij IDEA say that used properties are unused?

Tags: intellij-idea, properties-file

I have a properties file in my Java maven project. I have one class which loads these properties and stores them as constants.

```
//Constants.java file has this code.
Properties properties = new Properties(blah...);
String username = properties.getProperty("my.username");
System.out.println(username);
```

Despite using my.username property and the username variable, Intellij IDEA says that it is unused. Why ? I tried to invalidate caches and restart the IDE, but it did not change anything.

As a result, its hard to find out which properties are actually unused and remove them.

Here is the project structure :

```
PROJECT1

-> PROJECT2
--> src > main > resources > folder > my.properties
--> pom.xml

-> PROJECT3
--> src > main > java > packagea.b.c > packaged > packagee > Constants.java
--> pom.xml

pom.xml
```

Comment: Do you still need a better answer? Is there anything I can improve in mine?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Please give me some more time. I'll try to figure this out and get back.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not reproducible:

[image: unused property]

If you have the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please share it so that we can investigate why the it happens in your specific project.

Here is the properly working sample: [unused-properties.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/g36sxx3k3lr3aro/unused-properties.zip).

---

To match your multi module Maven project from the description I've created another sample project to illustrate the configuration and the properly working inspection.

Get the sample project here: [unused-multimodule-maven.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a7m70lpucx1cfhv/unused-multimodule-maven.zip).

This project has an aggregate `pom.xml` in the root directory and 2 modules: **app** and **properties** where **app** depends on **properties**.

Proof of working screenshot:

[image: Multi module Maven also works]

Notice that the [app module depends on the properties module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrWOu.png). This dependency is [achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INOdk.png) via the following `pom.xml` configuration of the **app** module.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I see this in proprietary code so I can't share code/videos/screenshots. I am trying to replicate the structure of the code base into an example that I can share. Meanwhile, are there any debugging tricks I could do to figure out why used properties show up as unused ?

Comment: I updated the question with the structure of the project. Hopefully, this will help. Unfortunately, I don't know how to replicate that structure with multiple poms. I just remember that such a structure is called a multi module project.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev does Project 3 depend on Project 2?

Comment: How do I check that ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

Comment: I selected Project3 > Analyze > Analyze module dependencies. Module dependencies tab opened on right. In tab, Project3 right click > Analyze dependencies > Analysis scope = Module Project3 > ok. I don't see Project2 in results. So, does this mean that Project3 is not dependent on Project2 ? Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev please see the updated answer with the Maven sample project. If it still doesn't work in your project, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).