# cannot resolve configuration property - intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I created a bare-minimum springboot project and it keeps complaining about the application.properties entries not being resolved. I have tried lowering the sprintboot version from 2.2.5 to lower ones but still the same issue. My intelliJ version is 2019.3.3 (ultimate version).

I do notice that standard spring config properties like below are picked up just fine from application.properties

```
# Cache resources for a day
spring.resources.cache.period=86400
```

Interestingly other projects that worked fine in the past have as well started giving this issue.
Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: Please see this answer and the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914910/104891. If it doesn't work for you, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the logs (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...) attached.